# No puedo separar ¬ dentro de una API con PHP

Tags: php, sql, api

Estoy trabajando en una API y al realizar la consulta obtengo por medio de:

```
$resp = file_get_contents($urlf, FALSE, $context);
```

El valor en `$resp` tiene el carácter  `¬` como separador o salto de línea, lo que quiero hacer es cambiarlo por salto de línea para poder crear un bucle y discriminar otros datos, pero no logro hacerlo.

Utilizo esta función:

```
$nuevotexto = str_replace("¬","<br>",$resp);
```

Y al momento de mostrarlo me sigue apareciendo el `¬`. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Desde dónde estás viendo la respuesta? Estás seguro que realmente está ese carácter y no que el visualizador simplemente te lo muestra para que se entienda que hay un salto de línea?